# CodeIgniter Models Don't Work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to read some data from database
my controller is

```
class Pro_ajax extends CI_Controller{
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    }
    public function _remap($method,$param = array())
    {
        if ($method == 'user_search')
        {
            $this->user_search($param[0]);
        }
    }
    private function user_search($text = '')
    {
        $result = $this->ajax_model->ajax_user_search($text);
        $count = count($result);
        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0;$i < $count AND $i < 5;$i++)
        {
            $data[$i][0] = $result->id;
            $data[$i][1] = $result->firstname.' '.$result->lastname;
        }
        echo (json_encode($data));
    }
}
```

and my model is :

```
class Ajax_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function ajax_user_search($text = '')
    {
       $this->db->flush_cache();
       $this->db->limit(5);
       $this->db->or_like('firstname',$text);
       $this->db->or_like('lastname',$text);
       $this->db->or_like('alias',$text);
       $this->db->or_like('username',$text);

       $query = $this->db->get('user_store_table');
       var_dump($this->db->last_query());
       return $query->result();   
    }   
}
```

but it doesn't work and echo following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Pro_ajax::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 50
```

where is the problem,and how should I solve it?
with special thanks for your attention

Comment: Have you autoload your database? in autoload file in config?

Comment: No,CI_Model doesn't do it by self?I extends my model from it

Comment: Which codeigniter version are you using? your code is a bit confusing. can you please post complete code as i can not see Pro_ajax anywhere.

Comment: that was the problem is'nt it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am 100% sure that you have not added database in your autoload.

please go to your config folder then open autoload.php and search for line having
$autoload['libraries'].

add this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

or you can do this:

```
class Ajax_model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: alphamale is a clever man :-) nice ans ....

Answer (score 3):

Looks like CI is interpreting $this as an instance of the controller instead of the database object...as cleverly pointed out by @AlphaMale, DID YOU LOADED IT?

```
   class Ajax_model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();   //No, database doesn't autoload by default
           //this is something which I strongly suggest to do in the config/autoload.php file..you're going to use it a lot in Models ;)
        }
        //..
    }
```

Also, autoloading a model in a controller might be considered "bad practice", since loading just-in-time increase (even if almost negligible amount on average) perforamnce.
So, I suggest loading your module right where you need it, i.e.

```
 private function user_search($text = '')
 {
   $this->load->model('ajax_model');
 }
```

And remove altogheter the __construct() from your controller, if you don't use it for other reasons.